# WordPress insert statement based on a database value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to insert statement in [share] table and update statement in [balance] table if balance is greater than or equal to 75 in balance table, But it is going to the else statement always, even though it meets necessary condition `balance>=75`

Following is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $site = htmlspecialchars($_POST['site']);
    $me=$current_user->user_login;
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $me=$current_user->user_login;
    $table_balance = $wpdb->prefix . "balance";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results(
        "SELECT Balance FROM $table_balance WHERE User= '$me'"
    );

    if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>=75) {
        $random = uniqid();
        $table_share = $wpdb->prefix . "share";
        $wpdb->insert( $table_share, array(
            'id' => $random,  
            'purchasedate' => $today, 
            'purchasevalue' => 75,
            'offervalue' => 0, 
            'status' => Active,
            'user' => $me, 
            'monthlyearnings' => 2,
        ));

        $sum=75;
        $table_balance = $wpdb->prefix . "balance";
        $wpdb->update(
            "$table_balance SET Balance=Balance-$sum WHERE User = '$me'"
        );
        echo "Purchased made successfully";
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "sorry!you dont have required amount.pls add required amount";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong function for checking the value of the database, `mysql_num_rows()` returns the number of rows returned by the query, in this case probably 1, and being smaller than 75 the `else` get always executed.

To obtain the balance you need to use [`fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php), something like this:

```
if ($result && ($row = $result->fetch_row()) && $row[0]>=75)
```

*Edit:* I put what you would use using the standard `mysqli_stmt::get_result` but you are using [`wpdb::get_results`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/), so the instead you have to use:

```
if ($result && $result[0]->Balance>=75)
```

Comment: hi thnks but now it is giving Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on array, however i have modified the query like following     '$result =  $wpdb->get_var("SELECT Balance FROM $table_balance WHERE User= '$me'");
if($result && $result>=75)' and its working.Thanks for your help

Comment: My bad, I put how you would get the results using the standard `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` but your are using `wpdb::get_results()`, which is different. Anyway `wpdb::get_var()` is better in this case since you only want to get only one vale of a single row.